# Is this C function for finding the product of an array correct?

Tags: c

I am new to C and have a question about making a simple function in which I hand in a given array and also an integer that tells the number of numbers in that array.  I wrote this code but I am unsure if it is correct.  What I was trying to do was to make it so that I could find the product of all the numbers in the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double my_product (int n, double x[]);

int main (void)
{
    my_product(n, x);
    return 0;
}

double my_product (int n, double x[])
{
    int i;
    product=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        product=x[i]*x[i+1]
    }
    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will comment your code, pointing out your mistakes:

```
double my_product (int n, double x[])
{
    int i;

    product=0;
    /* The variable "product" needs to have a type.  
       In your case, since your values have type "double",
       and a "double" return is expected, 
       of course you need to declare:

       double product;

       On the other hand, 
       it has not sense to initialize a product to 0,
       since multiplication by 0 "kills" every value,
       giving you a value 0, not matter what you do.
       So, initialize in this way:

       double product = 1.0;

    */

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        /* A semicolon is missing in the next line: */
        product=x[i]*x[i+1]

        /* In every step of the loop,
           the variable "product" will hold the value
           given by the multiplication of two consecutive values 
           in the array.
           Thus, you lose every previous factor.
           Also, when i == n you are in trouble, 
           because x[i] == x[n] is beyond the limits of the array,
           which may cause access violation to memory.

           You need a cumulative product.
           Starting by the initialized value 1.0,
           you have to multiply the previous value of "product" 
           with the present value of the array: x[i]

           product = product * x[i];

           Thus, in the step i, it can be proved that
           the variable "product" contains the cumulative product
           of the factors x[0], x[1], ... up to x[i].

           A more compact notation in C can be provided by the *= operator:

           product *= x[i];

           */
    }
    return product;
}
```

In the function `main()`:

```
int main (void) {          
    my_product(n, x);
    /* The function "my_product()" has been called with 
       undeclared parameters "n" and "x".

       First, you have to declare and define the value of "n",
       as much as the array "x", having type double:

       double x[] = {3.0, 1.41, -2.3, 9.4, };
       int n = sizeof(x)/sizeof(double);

       The first line would declare an array "x" having type "double",
       and initialized to hold 4 values, as it's seen there.
       The second line would declare an "int" variable "n" 
       holding the number of elements in the array,
       which can be computed as the size of x (measured in bytes)
       divided by the size of the type "double"
       (of course, in this example we have n == 4).

       Finally, you need to do something with the result returned by
       the function "my_product()".
       If not, the returned value will be completely lost.
       For example, to hold it in a variable, or to show it on screen.

       double ans;
       ans = my_product(n, x);
    */
    return 0; 
}
```

The code will look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double my_product (int n, double x[]);

int main (void)
{
    double x[] = {3.0, 1.41, -2.3, 9.4, };
    int n = sizeof(x)/sizeof(double);
    double ans;
    ans = my_product(n, x);
    printf("Product is: %f\n", ans);
    return 0;
}

double my_product (int n, double x[])
{
    product=1.0;
    int i;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        product *= x[i];
    }
    return product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `my_product` you overwrite the value of `product` in the loop

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    product=x[i]*x[i+1]
}
```

So suppose your array `x = {2, 3, 4}`, then first `product` gets the value of 2*3, but then you overwrite it with the value of 3*4. What you probably want is to use a variable in which you accumulate the results of the multiplications (e.g. `total = total * number`).

Also, watch out with your indexing. In your current code `i+1` can be larger than the number of elements in `x`, so you run out of the array.